# Google Analytics: Filter by custom dimensions

Tags: filter, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, custom-dimensions

I have added GA to a website by using GTM ID.
Everything is working fine, I can see active users on the website, events which I have created etc.
The problem is when I create a new view with a custom dimension filter.

[image]
[image]

In this case if I go to Real-time -> Events it is working, I can see filtered events
but **I always see 0 active users** on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Real time report is not reliable, try to check in effettive report if the data has been acquired.